# HTML Image does not display in Java

Tags: java, html, image

I'm trying to add some image to display in my program. But it did not display according to my expectation.

btw, I am using Captain Casa framework.
here is what I did.

```
m_html = "<span><img src=\\\"/images/icon/pichere.png\\\" alt=\"image description\"> </span>";
```

Comment: How are you displaying this? JLabel? Please include your code.

Comment: I already included my code.
I am using captain casa frame work. and I'm only displaying 1 image for now.

Comment: Did you checked the path to an image (I mean, is folder `images` in the root of classpath)?

Comment: indeed. I checked the path many times

Comment: May be you can attach the screenshot or smth more? ... try to set absolute path to an image to check that problem isn't in a path